# igdb.com api | React Axios request blocked by CORS policy; No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, cors

Despite this being a very common problem, the solutions I've searched don't seem to fix this for me.

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class GamesList extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount = async () => {
        const response = await axios.get("https://api-v3.igdb.com/games", {
            headers: {
                "user-key": "<API-KEY>",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:3000",
            },
        });
        console.log(response);
    };

    render() {
        return <div>MANY GAMES</div>;
    }
}

export default GamesList;
```

The error messages I receive from running this code is:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api-v3.igdb.com/games' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

GET https://api-v3.igdb.com/games net::ERR_FAILED

uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:83)
```

I've also tried setting `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"` though the error doesn't change.

Is there a simple fix for this that doesn't require using/creating a proxy?

--- UPDATE ---
following @HMR's comment, I've edited the code below as per igdb's documentation, though I'm still getting the same error. Where am I going wrong with this?

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class GamesList extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount = async () => {
        // As mention in the docs, I'm using POST with the necessary body
        axios.post("https://api-v3.igdb.com/headers", {
            body: {
                api_header: {
                    header: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
                    value: "*",
                },
            },
        });

        // now to make the actual request
        const response = await axios.get("https://api-v3.igdb.com/games", {
            headers: {
                "user-key": "<API-KEY>",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:3000",
            },
        });
        console.log(response);
    };

    render() {
        return <div>MANY GAMES</div>;
    }
}

export default GamesList;
```

Even posting the following to `https://api-v3.igdb.com/headers/` inside of postman returns `Not found`:

```
{
    "api_header": {
        "header": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
        "value": "*"
    }
}
```

-- FINAL UPDATE --
As @goto1 and @HMR have mentioned below, the api itself doesn't seem to support CORS correctly.

I've ended up going with a proxy in the end! I'm using https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/ (NOTE: I had to `npm install proxy-from-env` manually)

After starting up the server using `node server.js`, I can prepend the server's address to my igdb api request. Final code:

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class GamesList extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount = async () => {
        const response = await axios.get("http://0.0.0.0:8080/https://api-v3.igdb.com/games", {
            headers: {
                "user-key": "<API-KEY>",
            },
        });
        console.log(response); // WORKS!
    };

    render() {
        return <div>MANY GAMES</div>;
    }
}

export default GamesList;
```

Comment: *"tried setting `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin"`"* where? You can't set that from the client, it's a response header, so if `api-v3.igdb.com` doesn't set it (and you don't have the ownership to implement it) a proxy is your only option from clients that require CORS.

Comment: As in my code, I set this in the request headers

Comment: But that's in the *client*, not the *server*. If CORS could be bypassed by the client setting the header it would be totally pointless!

Comment: You need to tell the api [what cors header to provide](https://api-docs.igdb.com/#cors-for-js--ionic)

Comment: @HMR thank you for this - I've updated my code above. Could you please tell me where I'm going wrong? I'm following the documentation from what I can tell..

Comment: @solarflare that looks like it's "coming soon," so not sure you can do much at this point

Comment: Yes, I tried making the post request to the api to register a CORS that the api will send as **response header** but got a 404 so the `coming soon` part in the documentation really means that you can't use it now. In other words; you can't use client JavaScript to consume the api for now. That axios post you only need to make once as that is to configure your api settings.

Comment: As arslan hinted; you could set proxy in package.json: `"proxy": "https://api-v3.igdb.com/games"` and in your react code: `axios.get("/games"` but your code will only work in developer mode (with weppack dev server). If you publish it then your api provider need to have set up cors and you need to change your react code to use full url. Or you create a proxy on your server.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try ti set localhost:3000 in package.json instead in axios headers

Comment: Sorry how does this work? Is this for a proxy server?

Comment: Yes we set the proxy in package.json like "proxy": "http://localhost:4000",.

Comment: Here is official docs for this proxy method . Or remove headers from axios if not neccesryhttps://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/

Comment: Thank you for this - hmm for some reason. this doesn't quite work on my environment, but I have a solution now (see update above), and it's good to know this can be done!